# belongsToMany and belongsTo

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I created this query in my controller:

```
  $query = tag_performers::with('performers')->where('slug', '=', 'someting')->get();

  return view('frontend.newperformer')->with('hello', $query)
                                      ->with('sectionTitle', 'Performers');
```

I tested it in `Tinker` and it works. So I want to use it in my view file

```
@foreach($hello->performer as $h)
  {{ $h->performers->id }}
@endforeach
```

And I have the error

> "Property [performers] does not exist on this collection instance.(...)"

I don't know why. Who can help me?

Comment: Please show result of `dd($query);` and `performers` relationship.

Comment: performer vs performers. check the plurality of the variable you are using

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@foreach($hello->performer as $h)
   {{ $h->id }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume the query returns some data:

```
$query = tag_performers::with('performers')->where('slug', '=', 'someting')->get();
```

By the query it seems that `tag_performers` has many `performers` and vice versa, therfore you need to itterate twice.

```
  @foreach($hello->performers as $performers)
     @foreach($performers as $performer)
         {{$performer->id}}
     @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

But the title of the post it says `belongs to many and belongs to` so then the issue is you are accessing relationship and then trying to access the relationship again which does not make sens so it should be as:

```
  @foreach($hello->performer as $h)
    {{ $h->id }}
  @endforeach
```

Comment: It doen't work. I tried your second code before (I make mistake in my post) but it dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be the plurality of the variable that you are using

performer vs performer**s**

```
$query = tag_performers::with('performers')->where('slug', '=', 'someting')->get();

  return view('frontend.newperformer')->with('hello', $query)
                                      ->with('sectionTitle', 'Performers');



@foreach($hello->performers as $h) /* <-- notice the s  */
  {{ $h->performers->id }}
@endforeach
```